# Ember data hasMany issue cannot update parent object with child content

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a Contact model having multiple addresses.

```
Contact = DS.Model.extend({
   addresses : DS.hasMany('address')
});

Address = DS.Model.extend({
  street : DS.attr('string'),
  city : DS.attr('string'),
  state : DS.attr('string'),
  zip : DS.attr('string')
 });
```

Initially I just load a contact using `this.store.find('contact',1);` then I load all addresses related to it.

```
 this.store.find('address',{cId:1}).then(function(address){   
   model.set('addresses',address);
   self.set('model',model);
   // return addresses;
 });
```

As soon I try to set addresses above to the contact object I get the following error:

```
Error: Assertion Failed: Error: Cannot set read-only property "addresses" on object: <interval-intl-ember-clii@model:contact::ember496:null>
```

I'm not sure what the issue is. The thing I am trying to do above is trying to load child on demand rather than with parent initially for performance reasons and I have not been able to come across any working example to help me.

Any suggestions on what is happening above?

Answer (score 0):

Make addresses `async` to load them on demand, or don't define it at all in the model definition if you plan on manually setting it.

```
addresses : DS.hasMany('address', {async:true})
```

Comment: I did make it to {async:true}).

Comment: then you should not need to manually load them on demand. When you try to access the addresses with `model.get('addresses')` it will try to load them at that time.

Comment: my use case is to load the addresses separately and then do something like  this model.set('addresses',addressesCollection)but it is not working. even when i set {async:true}it doesnt work.

Comment: "or don't define it at all in the model definition if you plan on manually setting it."

Answer (score 0):

To populate an async relation you need to first 'open' it:

```
controller.get('addresses').then(function (result) {
  result.pushObjects(addresses);
})
```